# Array.prototype.slice.call stored in a variable throws error when invoked

Tags: javascript

`Array.prototype.slice.call` is a function, `typeof Array.prototype.slice.call` returns `"function"` and I can call it, e.g. `Array.prototype.slice.call([1])`.
I can store this function in a variable like so `const f = Array.prototype.slice.call`.  `typeof f` is still `"function"`, but if I try to call it now i get an error: `f([0]) => Uncaught TypeError: f is not a function at <anonymous>:1:1`.

Does someone know why I cant call `f` anymore?

Comment: You've lost the association between the `.call()` method and the `.slice()` method. Inside `.call`, `this` will be `undefined` so it can't work as it's designed to work.

Comment: `const f = Array.prototype.slice.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);` would overcome that issue.

Comment: This error message seems bugged anyway.